# Flask pip install with virtual environment (Raspberry Pi project)

Tags: python, flask, pip, raspberry-pi, virtualenv

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/monkeymademe/picamera2-WebUI-Lite) to use the HQ camera on a web interface.

I followed the [instructions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/installation/#install-flask) to install Flask by using a virtual environment and activate it to install it with `pip install Flask`.

But when it comes to run the  `app.py` (I installed the Picamera2 in the main environment), the terminal is telling me it can't find Flask. It's in another environment. So what is the purpose of this venv if I can't use the two things that are necessary to run the script?

I've tried to install Flask with `sudo apt install python3-flask` so all the dependencies were on the same environment, it worked when I ran the script (no errors).

I was expecting to access the web interface by putting the IP address of the Pi in my URL bar, but all I got was "connection failed" like there's nothing to connect to.

What do I have to do to make it work? I'm on Linux Mint by the way.

Comment: I think you need to install both `flask` and `Picamera2` in the same `venv`. This shows hows to install `Picamera2` using pip: https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2?tab=readme-ov-file#installation-using-pip After that install `flask` in the same environment and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: I followed your instructions in the same order, I get : 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nico/picamera2-WebUI-Lite/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from picamera2 import Picamera2
  File "/home/nico/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import libcamera
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libcamera'`

Comment: The author of this project told me it works on Windows... Is there an issue with Linux ? Because if I don't create any venv and install flask with `sudo apt install python3-flask`, the script runs perfectly, I just can't connect to the web interface.